# How to make Fullscreen button on Php desktop

Tags: php, fullscreen, phpdesktop

I am experimenting with Php desktop, and so far all is great. 
How ever I need to be able to have a button that will make it go to fullcreen and out (not only maximalized).
Is there a way to do it?
Or is there a way to start the aplication in browser?

Answer (score 2):

PHP desktop basically uses a browser (IE or Chrome). You can therefore use Javascript to go full screen. Like this:

```
<button id="goFS">Go fullscreen</button>
<script>
  var goFS = document.getElementById("goFS");
  goFS.addEventListener("click", function() {
      document.body.requestFullscreen();
  }, false);
</script>
```

For more details see: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/native-hardware/fullscreen/

Comment: Sadly, I have traied, this does not work, at least not on win 10

Comment: How about this link: https://github.com/cztomczak/phpdesktop/blob/master/phpdesktop-chrome47/www/javascript-api.php

Comment: I am sorry I forgot to answer. The link works perfectly! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

PHP Desktop exposes API to javascript under the "window.phpdesktop" object. To go full screen call `phpdesktop.ToggleFullscreen()`, to undo call it again.

See example:

https://github.com/cztomczak/phpdesktop/blob/2a800fecd8830e4f1e6c4054e74e8d03b4900847/phpdesktop-chrome57/www/javascript-api.php

See docs:

https://github.com/cztomczak/phpdesktop/wiki/Javascript-API